# Gram Schmidt with R

Tags: r, algorithm, matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

Here is a MATLAB code for performing Gram Schmidt in page 1
http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Essays/gramschmidtmat.pdf

I am trying for hours and hours to perform this with R since I don't have MATLAB
Here is my R

```
f=function(x){

  m=nrow(x);
  n=ncol(x);
  Q=matrix(0,m,n);
  R=matrix(0,n,n);

  for(j in 1:n){
    v=x[,j,drop=FALSE];

    for(i in 1:j-1){
      R[i,j]=t(Q[,i,drop=FALSE])%*%x[,j,drop=FALSE];
      v=v-R[i,j]%*%Q[,i,drop=FALSE]
    }

    R[j,j]=max(svd(v)$d);
    Q[,j,,drop=FALSE]=v/R[j,j]}

    return(list(Q,R))
  }
}
```

It keeps on saying there is errors in either:

```
v=v-R[i,j]%*%Q[,i,drop=FALSE]
```

or

```
R[j,j]=max(svd(v)$d);
```

What is it that I am doing wrong translating MATLAB code to R???

Comment: You may use Octave which is pretty close in functionalities to Matlab.  You can download it from internet for free. You need slight or no modifications at all to run your Matlab programs in Octave. But unlike Matlab, Octave has no native GUI and only terminal-like command execution. So, you might need a little time to get used to Octave.

Comment: I do not know whether the answers to this post might be helpful.  I did not try using your data with their approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238242/gram-schmidt-orthogonalization

Comment: Without having yet a deeper look, but at least your line `for(i in 1:j-1)` should be `for(i in 1:(j-1))` and then probably you have to use brackets also here `v=v-R[i,j]%*%Q[,i,drop=FALSE]`.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~yanovsky/Teaching/Math151B/handouts/GramSchmidt.pdf

Using matrix A from example 2, I am trying to get the same answer for Q and R

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply use Hans W. Borchers' [pracma package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/index.html), which provides many Octave/Matlab functions translated in R.

```
> library(pracma)
> gramSchmidt
function (A, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5) 
{
    stopifnot(is.numeric(A), is.matrix(A))
    m <- nrow(A)
    n <- ncol(A)
    if (m < n) 
        stop("No. of rows of 'A' must be greater or equal no. of colums.")
    Q <- matrix(0, m, n)
    R <- matrix(0, n, n)
    for (k in 1:n) {
        Q[, k] <- A[, k]
        if (k > 1) {
            for (i in 1:(k - 1)) {
                R[i, k] <- t(Q[, i]) %*% Q[, k]
                Q[, k] <- Q[, k] - R[i, k] * Q[, i]
            }
        }
        R[k, k] <- Norm(Q[, k])
        if (abs(R[k, k]) <= tol) 
            stop("Matrix 'A' does not have full rank.")
        Q[, k] <- Q[, k]/R[k, k]
    }
    return(list(Q = Q, R = R))
}
<environment: namespace:pracma>
```

Comment: I didn't about this package thanks, but it removes all the fun of programming it yourself. If you want to be efficient, just stick to the `qr` function in R which is fast enough (see the benchmark). Along this line, I was actually thinking about a Julia version too (but posting  someJulia code in the R section of SO can put you into trouble...)

Comment: @dickoa There are sufficiently other fun things to program with R :)

Answer (score 14):

Just for fun I added an Armadillo version of this code and benchmark it

Armadillo code :

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
List grahm_schimdtCpp(arma::mat A) {
    int n = A.n_cols;
    int m = A.n_rows;
    arma::mat Q(m, n);
    Q.fill(0);
    arma::mat R(n, n);
    R.fill(0);  
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    arma::vec v = A.col(j);
    if (j > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        R(i, j) = arma::as_scalar(Q.col(i).t() *  A.col(j));
        v = v - R(i, j) * Q.col(i);
        }
    }
    R(j, j) = arma::norm(v, 2);
    Q.col(j) = v / R(j, j);
    }
    return List::create(_["Q"] = Q,
                     _["R"] = R
    );
    }
```

R code not optimized (directly based on algorithm)

```
grahm_schimdtR <- function(A) {
    m <- nrow(A)
    n <- ncol(A)
    Q <- matrix(0, nrow = m, ncol = n)
    R <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = n)
    for (j in 1:n) {
    v <- A[ , j, drop = FALSE]
        if (j > 1) {
    for(i in 1:(j-1)) {
            R[i, j] <- t(Q[,i,drop = FALSE]) %*% A[ , j, drop = FALSE]
            v <- v - R[i, j] * Q[ ,i]
    }
    }
    R[j, j] = norm(v, type = "2")
    Q[ ,j] = v / R[j, j]
    }

    list("Q" = Q, "R" = R)

}
```

Native QR decomposition in R

```
qrNative <- function(A) {
    qrdec <- qr(A)
    list(Q = qr.R(qrdec), R = qr.Q(qrdec))
}
```

We will test it with the same matrix as in original document (link in the post above)

```
A <- matrix(c(4, 3, -2, 1), ncol = 2)

all.equal(grahm_schimdtR(A)$Q %*% grahm_schimdtR(A)$R, A)
## [1] TRUE

all.equal(grahm_schimdtCpp(A)$Q %*% grahm_schimdtCpp(A)$R, A)
## [1] TRUE

all.equal(qrNative(A)$Q %*% qrNative(A)$R, A)
## [1] TRUE
```

Now let's benchmark it

```
require(rbenchmark)
set.seed(123)
A <- matrix(rnorm(10000), 100, 100)
benchmark(qrNative(A),
          grahm_schimdtR(A),
          grahm_schimdtCpp(A),
          order = "elapsed")
##                  test replications elapsed relative user.self
## 3 grahm_schimdtCpp(A)          100   0.272    1.000     0.272
## 1         qrNative(A)          100   1.013    3.724     1.144
## 2   grahm_schimdtR(A)          100  84.279  309.849    95.042
##   sys.self user.child sys.child
## 3    0.000          0         0
## 1    0.872          0         0
## 2   72.577          0         0
```

I really love how easy to port code into Rcpp....

Comment: +1! funny and excellent initiative to translate this to an Rcpp code.

Answer (score 7):

If you are translating code in Matlab into R, then code semantics (code logic) should remain same. For example, in your code, you are transposing Q in `t(Q[,i,drop=FALSE])` as per the given Matlab code. But `Q[,i,drop=FALSE]` does not return the column in column vector. So, we can make it a column vector by using the statement:

```
matrix(Q[,i],n,1); # n is the number of rows.
```

There is no error in `R[j,j]=max(svd(v)$d)` if `v` is a vector (row or column).

Yes, there is an error in

```
v=v-R[i,j]%*%Q[,i,drop=FALSE]
```

because you are using a matrix multiplication. Instead you should use a normal multiplication:

```
v=v-R[i,j] * Q[,i,drop=FALSE]
```

Here `R[i,j]` is a number, whereas `Q[,i,drop=FALSE]` is a vector. So, dimension mismatch arises here.

One more thing, if `j` is 3 , then `1:j-1` returns [0,1,2]. So, it should be changed to `1:(j-1)`, which returns [1,2] for the same value for `j`. But there is a catch. If `j` is 2, then `1:(j-1)` returns [1,0]. So, 0th index is undefined for a vector or a matrix. So, we can bypass `0` value by putting a conditional expression.

Here is a working code for Gram Schmidt algorithm:

```
A = matrix(c(4,3,-2,1),2,2)
m = nrow(A)
n = ncol(A)
Q = matrix(0,m,n)
R = matrix(0,n,n)

for(j in 1:n)
{
    v = matrix(A[,j],n,1)
    for(i in 1:(j-1))
    {
        if(i!=0)
        {
            R[i,j] = t(matrix(Q[,i],n,1))%*%matrix(A[,j],n,1)
            v = v - (R[i,j] * matrix(Q[,i],n,1))
        }
    }
    R[j,j] = svd(v)$d 
    Q[,j] = v/R[j,j]
}
```

If you need to wrap the code into a function, you can do so as per your convenience.

Comment: **R** should be an `n * n` square matrix.

Comment: I want to vote up but I don't have enough reputation to do it yet. Thank you for explanations along with the code!

Answer (score 5):

Here a version very similar to yours but without the use of the extra variabale v. I use directly the Q matrix. So no need to use `drop`. Of course since you have `j-1` in the index you need to add the condition `j>1`.

```
f=function(x){
  m <- nrow(x)
  n <- ncol(x)
  Q <- matrix(0, m, n)
  R <- matrix(0, n, n)
  for (j in 1:n) {
    Q[, j] <- x[, j]
    if (j > 1) {
      for (i in 1:(j - 1)) {
        R[i, j] <- t(Q[, i]) %*% Q[, j]
        Q[, j] <- Q[, j] - R[i, j] * Q[, i]
      }
    }
    R[j, j] <- max(svd(Q[, j])$d)
    Q[, j] <- Q[, j]/R[j, j]
  }
  return(list(Q = Q, R = R))
}
```

**EDIT** add some benchmarking:

To get some real case I use the `Hilbert` matrix from the `Matrix` package.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(Matrix)
A <- as.matrix(Hilbert(100))
microbenchmark(grahm_schimdtR(A),
               grahm_schimdtCpp(A),times = 100L)

Unit: milliseconds
expr       min         lq     median        uq        max neval
grahm_schimdtR(A) 330.77424 335.648063 337.443273 343.72888 601.793201   100
grahm_schimdtCpp(A)   1.45445   1.510768   1.615255   1.66816   2.062018   100
```

As expected **CPP** solution is really fster.

Comment: I want to vote up but I don't have enough reputation to do it yet. I didn't try this yet but thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

A verbatim implementation of the following `matlab` [code](http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Essays/gramschmidtmat.pdf) (shown in the next figure) in base `R` to obtain *orthonormal* basis vectors with Gram-Schmidt algorithm is shown below:

[image]

```
Gram_Schmidt <- function(A) {
  n <- ncol(A)
  Q <- 0*A
  R <- matrix(rep(0, n*n), nrow=n)
  for (j in 1:n) {
    v <- A[,j]
    if (j > 1) # the first basis vector to be included in Q anyway (after normalization)
      for (i in 1:(j-1)) {
        R[i, j] <- t(Q[,i]) %*% A[,j]
        v <- v - R[i,j] * Q[,i] # subtract the projections on other orthonormal basis vectors constructed so far
      }
    R[j,j] <- sqrt(v %*% v)
    Q[,j] <- v / R[j,j]
  }
  return(list(Q=Q, R=R))
}
```

Given the matrix `A`, we obtain the following results as expected:

```
A <- matrix(c(4,3,-2,1), nrow=2)
Gram_Schmidt(A)

#$Q
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  0.8 -0.6
# [2,]  0.6  0.8

#$R
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    5   -1
#[2,]    0    2
```

Using `QR` decomposition with base `R` again,

```
Gram_Schmidt_QR <- function(A) {
  res <- qr(A)
  return(list(Q=qr.Q(res), R=qr.R(res)))
}


Gram_Schmidt_QR(A)
#$Q
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  0.8 -0.6
# [2,]  0.6  0.8

#$R
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    5   -1
#[2,]    0    2
```

Also, we could use `R` library `matlib`'s implementation, it only outputs the orthonormal `Q` matrix though and not the upper triangular matrix `R`:

```
library(matlib)
GramSchmidt(A)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  0.8 -0.6
#[2,]  0.6  0.8
```

Finally, some performance benchmarking gives the following result:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(microbenchmark)
autoplot(microbenchmark(Gram_Schmidt(A),
                        Gram_Schmidt_QR(A),
                        GramSchmidt(A), times=1000L))
```

[image]