# trouble with for loops in R, replicating the Gram-Schmidt Orthonormalization algorithm

Tags: r, algorithm

I am trying to replicate the Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization algorithm for my linear algebra class in R. First I generate some data, and store it in matrix `A`

```
a1<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
a2<-c(4,5,2,9,1,2)
a3<-c(2,2,2,3,3,3)
A<-cbind(a1,a2,a3)
```

I then run the gram-schmidt orthonormalization algorithm to convert the columns of A into a orthonormal set, stored in the matrix `Q`.

```
R=matrix(0,nrow=ncol(A),ncol=ncol(A))
Q=A
R[1,1]=sqrt(sum(Q[,1]*Q[,1])) #calculate nrom of q1, store in R
Q[,1]=(1/R[1,1])*Q[,1] #transform q1 into a unit vector, using the norm stored in R.
for(j in 2:ncol(Q))
{
    for(i in 1:j-1)
    {
        R[i,j]=sum(Q[,i]*Q[,j]) 
        Q[,j]=Q[,j] - R[i,j]*Q[,i] 
    }
    R[j,j]=sqrt(sum(Q[,j]*Q[,j]))#calulate the norm of qj, store in the main diagonal of R
    Q[,j]=(1/R[j,j])*Q[,j] #transform qj into a unit vector, using the norm stored in R.
}
```

My algorithm seems very similar to some of the ones coded here for R: [Gram Schmidt with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584221/gram-schmidt-with-r)

However, every time I run the algorithm it generates this error:

```
Error in Q[, j] = Q[, j] - R[i, j] * Q[, i] : replacement has length zero
```

I can't figure out what is wrong here. If I run the code line by line, and set i=1, j=2, it runs the first computation of this line just fine. Is there something wrong with how I have specified or nested my for loops? Bueller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range in the second loop should be `1:(j-1)`.

To illustrate the problem:

```
> 1:4-1
[1] 0 1 2 3
```

while

```
> 1:(4-1)
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Note that if, by any chance, your code would get a one column input it would fail. The range of the other loop `2:ncol(Q)` would be `2:1`, i.e. `c(2,1)` and it would try to access the second column instead of not doing the loop at all.

Comment: Here is more about it: http://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2008/08/06/design-flaws-in-r-1-reversing-sequences/