# Gram Schmidt orthonomalisation (row-wise) using Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

I am trying to obtain a matrix consisting of row-wise normalized orthogonal vectors based on an m-by-n matrix where m < n using Rcpp within R. Unfortunately, I was not able to figure out how to employ the *qr* method implemented in R to do this.

My attempt closely follows the standard Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization algorithm, which has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584221/gram-schmidt-with-r). However, the approach presented in this thread using Rcpp and Armadillo does not seem to work anymore.

An implementation for the problem in Matlab is provided by Gary Koop in his [collection of computer codes](https://sites.google.com/site/garykoop/home/computer-code-2):

```
function [Q] = grams(A)
[m,~] = size(A);

Q=0*A;
% compute QR using Gram-Schmidt
for j = 1:m
   v = A(j,:);
   for i=1:j-1
        v = v - Q(i,:)*A(j,:)'*Q(i,:);
   end
   Q(j,:) = v/norm(v);
end
```

My current Rcpp code is the following:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP gramscpp(arma::mat A){
  int m = A.n_rows;
  int n = A.n_cols;
  arma::mat Q(m,n); Q.fill(0);

  Q.row(0) = A.row(0)/arma::norm(A.row(0),2);
  for(int j = 1; j < m; j++){
    arma::rowvec v = A.row(j);
    for(int i = 0; i < (j-1); i++){
      v = v - (Q.row(i) * A.row(j).t()) * Q.row(i);
    }
    Q.row(j) = v/arma::norm(v,2);
  }
  return Rcpp::wrap(Q);
}
```

When simulating a random m-by-n matrix and applying the algorithm, no errors occur. However, the resulting matrix multiplied by its transpose does not yield an identity matrix and I am not able to identify the mistake.

Comment: Your indexing is wrong. 1...j-1 becomes 0..j-2 etc.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that it was indeed an indexing problem. Using for(int i = 0; i < j; i++) for the second loop gives the correct result.

Comment: Ok, I think we can close this then.