# Trying to do PCA analysis on interest rate swaps data (multivariate time series)

Tags: time-series, regression, pca, finance

I have a data set with 20 non-overlapping different swap rates (spot1y, 1y1y, 2y1y, 3y1y, 4y1y, 5y2y, 7y3y, 10y2y, 12y3y...) over the past year.

I want to use PCA / multiregression and look at residuals in order to determine which sectors on the curve are cheap/rich. Has anyone had experience with this? I've done PCA but not for time series. I'd ideally like to model something similar to the first figure here but in USD. 
https://plus.credit-suisse.com/rpc4/ravDocView?docid=kv66a7

Thanks!

Comment: Here’s a really nice write-up by Jon Shlens, which deals specifically with temporal data: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.1100.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Here are some broad strokes that can help answer your question. Also, that's a neat analysis from CS :)

Let's be pythonistas and use NumPy. You can imagine your dataset as a `20x261` array of `float`s. The first place to start is [creating the array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.array-creation.html#routines-array-creation).  Suppose you have a CSV file storing the raw data persistently.  Then a reasonable first step to load the data would be something as simple as:

```py
import numpy

x = numpy.loadtxt("path/to/my/file")
```

The object `x` is our raw time series matrix, and we verify the truthness of `x.shape == (20, 261)`.  The next step is to transform this array into it's covariance matrix. Whether it has been done on the raw data already, or it still has to be done, the first step is centering each time series on it's mean, like this:

```py
x_centered = x - x.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

The purpose of this step is to help simplify any necessary rescaling, and is a very good habit that usually shouldn't be skipped. The call to `x.mean` uses the parameters `axis` and `keepdims` to make sure each *row* (e.g. the time series for `spot1yr`, ...) is centered with *it's* mean value.

The next steps are to square and scale `x` to produce a swap rate covariance array. With 2-dimensional arrays like `x`, there are two ways to square it-- one that leads to a `261x261` array and another that leads to a `20x20` array.  It's the second array we are interested in, and the squaring procedure that will work for our purposes is:

```py
x_centered_squared = numpy.matmul(x_centered, x_centered.transpose())
```

Then, to scale one can chose between `1/261` or `1/(261-1)` depending on the statistical context, which looks like this:

```py
x_covariance = x_centered_squared * (1/261)
```

The array `x_covariance` has an entry for how each swap rate changes with itself, and changes with any one of the other swap rates.  In linear-algebraic terms, it is a symmetric operator that characterizes the spread of each swap rate.

Linear algebra *also* tells us that this array can be decomposed into it's associated eigen-spectrum, with elements in this spectrum being scalar-vector pairs, or eigenvalue-eigenvector pairs.  In the analysis you shared, `x_covariance`'s eigenvalues are plotted in exhibit two as percent variance explained. To produce the data for a plot like exhibit two (which you will always want to furnish to the readers of your PCA), you simply divide each eigenvalue by the sum of all of them, then multiply each by `100.0`. Due to the convenient properties of `x_covariance`, a suitable way to compute it's spectrum is like this:

```py
vals, vects = numpy.linalg.eig(x_covariance)
```

We are now in a position to talk about residuals! Here is their definition (with our namespace): `residuals_ij = x_ij − reconstructed_ij; i = 1:20; j = 1:261`. Thus for every datum in `x`, there is a corresponding residual, and to find them, we need to recover the `reconstructed_ij` array. We can do this column-by-column, operating on each `x_i` with a *change of basis* operator to produce each `reconstructed_i`, each of which can be viewed as coordinates in a *proper subspace* of the original or raw basis. The analysis describes a modified Gram-Schmidt approach to compute the change of basis operator we need, which ensures this proper subspace's basis *is an orthogonal set*.

What we are going to do in the approach is take the eigenvectors corresponding to the three largest eigenvalues, and transform them into three mutually orthogonal vectors, `x`, `y`, `z`. Research the web for active [discussions](https://gist.github.com/iizukak/1287876/edad3c337844fac34f7e56ec09f9cb27d4907cc7) and [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238242/gram-schmidt-orthogonalization) geared toward developing the Gram-Schmidt process for all sorts of practical applications, but for simplicity let's follow the analysis by hand:

```py
x = vects[0] - sum([])
xx = numpy.dot(x, x)


y = vects[1] - sum(
    (numpy.dot(x, vects[1]) / xx) * x
)
yy = numpy.dot(y, y)


z = vects[2] - sum(
    (numpy.dot(x, vects[2]) / xx) * x,
    (numpy.dot(y, vects[2]) / yy) * y
)
```

It's reasonable to implement normalization before or after this step, which should be informed by the data of course.

Now with the raw data, we implicitly made the assumption that the basis is standard, we need a map between `{e1, e2, ..., e20}` and `{x,y,z}`, which is given by

```py
ch_of_basis = numpy.array([x,y,z]).transpose()
```

This can be used to compute each `reconstructed_i`, like this:

```py
reconstructed = []
for measurement in x.transpose().tolist():
    reconstructed.append(numpy.dot(ch_of_basis, measurement))

reconstructed = numpy.array(reconstructed).transpose()
```

And then you get the residuals by subtraction:

```py
residuals = x - reconstructed
```

This flow obviously might need further tuning, but it's the gist of how to do compute all the residuals.  To get that periodic bar plot, take the average of each row in `residuals`.